# Polar form equations on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $l \in [0, 2 π)$, $k, n \in N$, proof the following equations:

$$\mid{e^{i k l/n} - e^{i (k-1) l/n}}\mid = \mid e^{i l/n} - 1\mid$$

and:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n \mid e^{i k l/n} - e^{i (k-1) l/n} \mid = l$$

Any help would be much appreciated. I've tried drawing these equations with concrete examples on the unit circle, and they intuitively make sense, but I'm not sure on how to prove them.

Comment: And consider taking a look at this [thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers). It's also important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

$$|e^{ikl/n} - e^{ikl}e^{-il/n}| = |e^{ikl/n}||1 - e^{-il/n}| = |\frac{1}{e^{il/n}}||e^{il/n} - 1| = |e^{il/n} - 1|$$

We have that $\displaystyle{\sum _{k=1}^{n}} \ 1 = n$.

Hence

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum _{k=1}^{n}|e^{ikl/n} - e^{ikl}e^{-il/n}| = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum _{k=1}^{n}|e^{il/n} - 1| = \lim_{n\to\infty}n|e^{il/n} - 1|$$

Remember that $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$, $|e^{ix}| = \sqrt{\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x}$ and $\cos x = 1 - 2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$e^{i(k-1)l/n}$ is a complex number with modulus one, hence it can be factored away from the LHS of the first equation, giving identity. For the same reason, the second sum equals:
$$ n\cdot|1-e^{il/n}| = 2n\cdot\sin\frac{l}{2n}$$
and since $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, the limit equals $l$.